# .htaccess add www. doesn't work like expected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to add a www. to my domain. If someone goes to 'mydomain.com' it needs to be send to 'www.mydomain.com'. This all works fine. The problem is if someone types in 'mydomain.com/subfolder/subfolder3' it redirects to 'www.mydomain.com/mydomain/subfolder/subfolder3' instead of 'www.mydomain.com/subfolder/subfolder3'

My .htaccess is located in the htdocs folder beside the www folder.

My .htaccess:

```
php_flag display_errors Off

php_value upload_max_filesize 25M
php_value post_max_size 25M

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myseconddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]

AuthUserFile /home/bla/bla/bla/domains/mydomain/htdocs/beta/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "WebDav only for authorized users"
AuthType Basic

<LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

As you can see there are 2 domains. If someone types in the second domain it also needs to redirect to the first domain.

The 'AuthUserFile' you can see doesn’t exist anymore. Can I safely delete everything beneath it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mydomain|(www\.)?myseconddomain)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.myseconddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Still the same problem. If i go to 'mydomain.com/subfolder/subfolder3' it redirects to 'www.mydomain.com/mydomain/subfolder/subfolder3'. it adds a extra subfolder. if i go to 'myseconddomain.com' is redirects to 'www.mydomain.com//' with 2 slashes. I don't know if this is a big problem.

Comment: **edit:** the extra subfolder only gets there if my url ends with 'someting.php'. if i go to 'index.php' there is no problem and it work perfect. if i go to 'www.myseconddomain.com' it does not change to 'www.mydomain.com'

Comment: Works great now. Trying in new browser is the key.

Comment: Hi there again. Could you help me out one more time. I'm using your script above only when I go to a subfolder like: subfolder.myseconddomain.com it stays at myseconddomain.com instaid of rewriting to subfolder.mydomain.com.

Comment: Uhm. This one gives a internal server error on every page i try to visit.

Comment: There was a typo that I have fixed now.

Comment: Indeed a typo. Now the error is gone. Only stil no adress change. It stays subdomain.myseconddomain.com